# AppendChild to iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Via javascript (a bookmarklet): I need to create an iframe and then add a form to it and then a script that submits the form.

The following works in Chrome, but not in IE:

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe'); // also give it id = iframe_id
var frm = document.createElement('form');  // also add inputs and values
var s = document.createElement('script'); // also add innerHTML that submits form 

document.body.appendChild(i);
window.frames['iframe_id'].document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(frm);
window.frames['iframe_id'].document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

In IE I get an error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference

I tried to append the form and script to the iframe, before adding the iframe to the document:

```
 i.appendChild(frm);
 i.appendChild(s);
 document.body.appendChild(i);
```

I get a weird response in Chrome. The response from the form submit appears in a blocked pop-up (instead of not at all, which I expect). In IE nothing much seems to happen.

Comment: What versions of IE do you intend to support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest writing directly to the document using `write()` initially.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QjPuZ/1/

Code:

```
var iframeDoc = i.contentDocument || i.contentWindow.document;

iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write("<html><body></body></html>");
iframeDoc.close();

iframeBody = iframeDoc.body;
var frm = iframeDoc.createElement('form');
var s = iframeDoc.createElement('script');
iframeBody.appendChild(frm);
iframeBody.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: That actually seems to do the trick. Any idea why? (Wondering if it will always work or is a quirky thing, maybe having to do with giving it a little extra time)

Comment: @user984003: I'm not entirely sure what is actually supposed to happen. It's possible the HTML5 spec says something about it. I just have long experience of trial and error with loading stuff into iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Your example didn't work just because the element needs to be created inside the frame.

```
var o = iframeDoc.createElement('form');
iframeDoc.appendChild(o); // "body" is not present in IE, but it works
```